# Image URL works, but will not show using an IMG tag

Tags: html, image

I'm struggling to get images to show on my webpage.  Other images work just fine but the images with a dash in the file name will not display.

Here is my webpage.  I've taken everything out in an attempt to troubleshoot.

```
<html>  
    <body>      
        <img src="http://localhost/CloerOutdoor/ads/footer/HTE_fleet_program-728x90.jpg" />
     </body> 
</html>
```

Here is what I see when I "inspect" the page:

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">window["_gaUserPrefs"] = { ioo : function() { return true; } }
</script><head>
</head>
<body data-new-gr-c-s-check-loaded="14.1135.0" data-gr-ext-installed="">
    <img src="http://localhost/CloerOutdoor/ads/footer/HTE_fleet_program-728x90.jpg">
</body><grammarly-desktop-integration data-grammarly-shadow-root="true"></grammarly-desktop-integration></html>
```

I have removed all code except the IMG tag but the problem remains.  If I remove the dash from the file name, it displays just fine.  I'd like to get it to work WITH the dash in the file name because there are thousands of files with a dash.

When I "inspect" the page, it shows the correct URL in the IMG tag.  I can copy that link address and paste it into a browser and it works.

I get the same result on Chrome and Edge.  I have cleared the browser history and cached files.  I have even restarted the webserver to clear any cache that may be there.

The expected result is that the image displays normally, with the dash in the file name.

Comment: The described behavior is definitely strange.  In your browser's debugging tools, on the network tab, when you load the page is a request made for the image?  Is the URL of that request what you expect?  What is the server's response?  Is there any way you can provide a live running example which demonstrates the problem so we can observe it too?

Comment: The URL has `/ads/` in it. You probably have a browser extension installed which is blocking it.

Comment: @Quentin, I added my localhost as "trusted" in my ad blocker and the image shows now.  But, the question remains, why would the image load without the dash but was blocked when it had a dash in the name?   Also, I changed the path to images/footer, taking out "ads" and still have the same issue.

Comment: I can't see the specific rules your ad blocker is using.

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.